# Azure Metric: dtu_used does not accept zero dimension case

Tags: azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to get the metrics of Microsoft.Sql/servers/ resource:
The resource_id is: `/subscriptions/******-8**2-44**-95**-****13a5****/resourceGroups/SQLTesting/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqltest`
As in example [metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/monitoring?view=azure-python#example---metrics)

```
resource_id="/subscriptions/******-8**2-44**-95**-****13a5****/resourceGroups/SQLTesting/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqltest"
today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    metrics_data = client.metrics.list(
        resource_id,
        timespan="{}/{}".format(yesterday, today),
        interval='PT1H',
        metricnames='dtu_used',
        aggregation='Average'
    )

    for item in metrics_data.value:
        # azure.mgmt.monitor.models.Metric
        print("{} ({})".format(item.name.localized_value, item.unit.name))
        for timeserie in item.timeseries:
            for data in timeserie.data:
                # azure.mgmt.monitor.models.MetricData
                print("{}: {}".format(data.time_stamp, data.total))
```

But I am getting **ErrorResponseException: Metric: dtu_used does not accept zero dimension case** error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In metric definition, there is a property called `isDimensionRequired`, when querying for its value you must provide a filter for the dimension; if you do not do so the metric query will fail.

So, for `dtu_used` metric of SQL Server, the value is true which means that you need to provide the `DataBaseResourceId` in filter.

[image]

Here is a ample:

[image]

So, basically, you need to add a filter in the metric query.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your issue, the metric `dtu_used` is for the sql db not the sql server, i.e for the resource type `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases`, not `Microsoft.Sql/servers`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftsqlserversdatabases).

To fix the issue, you need to use the `resource_id` with the resource id of a specific sql db, like `/subscriptions/******-8**2-44**-95**-****13a5****/resourceGroups/SQLTesting/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/sqltest/databases/Mydatabase`, then it will work fine.